# Setting environment variables for application Maven

Tags: maven

My question is i have a pom file which calls a bat file which sets environment variables for the application. Then i call the ant script which uses these environment variables to compile and execute. These environment variables cant be recognized by ant script and it fails. I believe its because both run in different context. Can you guys let me know how to link this together.

org.codehaus.mojo
        exec-maven-plugin
        1.1
        
          
            Pre_Clean
            pre-clean
            
              exec
            
            
              
              env.bat
            
          

      
      
        maven-antrun-plugin
        
     
            Compile
            compile
            
              run

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  When the batch file ends the environment changes go out of scope.  So, you need to call ant from within your .bat file OR set up the environment before starting maven OR set them up in the POM.